# Understanding Objective-C throw call stack

Tags: objective-c, crash, osx-lion, callstack

A user has just submitted a bug report to me, saying that my app crashed. The user also attached a throw call stack.

The part which seems to have caused the problem is:

```
       3   My App                0x000000010d005483 My App + 17539
```

Is there a way to translate that address and/or the `+ 17539` to a line number in my code?

Keep in mind, I wasn't able to reproduce the bug on my machine, so I can't just build it in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [Tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html) from Apple.

> ... This trace is similar to what you would see when stopping execution in the debugger, except that you are not given the method or function names, known as symbols. Instead, you have hexadecimal addresses and executable code - your application or system frameworks - to which they refer. You need to map these addresses to symbols. Unlike crash logs from Mac OS X, iPhone OS logs do not contain symbol information when they're written out. You have to symbolicate iPhone OS logs before you can analyze them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading through it now, I noticed though that it talks about iPhone OS Crash Reports, but my app is a desktop (Mac OS X) one, is it any different for Mac OS X crash reports?

Comment: I believe there is still the whole symbolication process but sorry I prob should not have posted an iS specific link. Check this blog post on [Symbolicating crash logs](http://fourdman.blogspot.com/2011/05/symbolicating-crash-logs.html)

Comment: @houbysoft: In general, if you drag the crash log into Xcode's organizer, and you have the necessary files on-disk for symbolication (e.g. the app and its dSYM), then Xcode will symbolicate for you.

Comment: @KevinBallard: right, but I don't have the full crash report, only the call stack. @Paul.s: thanks for that link, however, when I try to use `dwarfdump`'s `--lookup` function with the address it never finds anything...

Comment: @houbysoft: You can also try the `atos` utility.

Comment: @KevinBallard: I tried that too, but it doesn't seem to find anything either, it only prints back the address I specify

Comment: @houbysoft: Do you actually have the .dSYM and app on your drive (and sitting right next to each other)?

Comment: Have the user send you the full crash report.  It's saved on his machine by CrashReporter.

Comment: @wadesworld: I'll try that I guess

Answer (score 1):

I've been using GDB to do manual symbolication. It'd be too cumbersome if you were doing it a lot, but the typical crash log doesn't have very many symbols, and I only need to symbolicate a crash log once in a while.

The procedure is as follows:

1. Put the .dSYM file for your app in the same folder as the .app.*
2. Open Terminal and `cd` to the folder from step 1.
3. Start your app up in GDB:
   `$ gdb YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp`
4. Set the print asm-demangle and print symbol-file options:
   `set print asm-demangle on`
   `set print symbol-filename on`
5. Use the p/a command to find the line numbers for each address in your stack trace:
   `p/a 0x000000010d005483`

These instructions are from [this page](http://www.picsoftware.ca/blog/?p=8) (apparently no longer online).

*Note that the .dSYM has a UDID tying it to the particular build it was created with. So, if you don't have the original .dSYM file, you're in trouble. Theoretically, you can't even just pull the same revision from source control and rebuild because this UDID will be different.

Comment: Just tried, but after I type `p/a 0x000000010d005483` I only get `$1 = 0x10d005483`, no line numbers or anything...